# Trying to set value using shuffle

Tags: php, arrays, logic, shuffle

Ok so here's my problem. I have an array of names. I want to setup where one name points to another, in a random order. But without any name pointing at itself. I want each value to be pointed to by a different value and each value to only point to one value, not itself. *Wish I could think of a better way to phrase that.* Here is the method I'm using at the moment

```
    while($xcount>=1){
        $orderarray[($xcount-1)]=$xcount;
        $xcount--;
    }
    shuffle($orderarray);
```

The problem is I don't want $orderarry[$x] to equal [$x] which seems to happen almost everytime. Is there a way to do this.

Anyhow I'm trying to virtually do what happens when a group of people all put their names in a hat and each person then picks a name out of the hat. Like for a secret santa.

Comment: Let's suppose that you have [1,2,3,4] is it legit to get 12,21,34,43?

Comment: That won't happen for as you can see I set the values from 1 to the size of the array using the $xcount variable. So it comes out 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... ect.

Comment: Then, please add to the question examples of input and output data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$names = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
shuffle($names);
while (key($names) !== null)
    {
    $current = current($names);
    $next = next($names);
    if ($next) // is not last
        $bonds[] = [$current, $next];
    }
$bonds[] = [end($names), reset($names)]; // last
var_dump($bonds);
```

Comment: This creates an array of arrays, which doesn't really help with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with the following code, by getting a random number and making sure that number hasn't been used and is not pointing to itself.

```
    $neworder=array();
    $xcount=count($gmemberarray);
    //fill the array with numbers and a setting of false *hasn't been used*
    while($xcount>=1){
        //$orderarray[($xcount-1)]=arrray();
        $orderarray[($xcount-1)][0]=($xcount-1);
        $orderarray[($xcount-1)][1]=false;
        $xcount--;
    }
    $xcount=count($gmemberarray);
    $count=$xcount;
    while($xcount>=1){
        R:
        $randnum=rand(0, ($count-1));
        if($orderarray[$randnum][1]==true) //If it's already been used get a different number
            goto R; //otherwise try again
        if($xcount!=$randnum){ //if it's not equal to itself
            $neworder[($xcount-1)]=$randnum;
            $orderarray[$randnum][1]=true;
            echo "<br><br>Neworder ".$xcount.": ".$neworder[($xcount-1)];
        }
        else
            goto R; //otherwise try again
        $xcount--;

    }
```

Input data would be:

```
    orderarray[1]=1
    orderarray[2]=2
    orderarray[3]=3
    orderarray[4]=4
```

And an example of the output I was hoping for was:

```
    orderarray[1]=3
    orderarray[2]=4
    orderarray[3]=2
    orderarray[4]=1
```

Comment: Let me see examples of input and output data.